# NoSuchElementException, django, selenium web driver

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

I'm trying to write a series of tests for mine application, so I'm starting with basic, but there is small error and I'm facing `NoSuchElementException` because I'm not correctly fetching hyperlinks by link text.

I want to find and click on a hyperlink which will get me to `about` page link so I'm in `functional_tests`

```
def test_click_on_about_link_navbar_get_users_to_about_page(self):
    """TODO: Docstring for test_societe_navbar_get_user_to_about_page.
    :returns: Click on navbar and return about page

    """
    self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('About').click()
    self.assertIn('http://localhost:8000/about', self.driver.current_url)
```

and the element's I'm trying to find

```
<li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
```

What I'm I missing, can someone explain me how to do this correctly.

Comment: Can you check if these `<li> ` elements located inside `<iframe>`?

Comment: No they are inside `<ul>`, I just didn't paste complete `navbar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(lambda browser: self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li/a[contains(text(), "About")]'))
```

Comment: I have tried xpath before, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but there was another error, mine tests was not fetching `localhost:8000`, after correcting that, everything is working, and that previous `xpath` code, and mine too, nevertheless thank you.